# Monkey Patch restify response before sending the response

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm trying to apply JSON mask (not related to Friday 13th game or movie) on my **restify** json **response**.

> The normal way to do it is to call next() in all server routes, then
>   implement the mask in the 'pre' handler of restify

I can't do it right now, I'm going for a quick fix so I'm trying monkey patch my restify response as follows :

Create a module 'CustomResponse' :

```
function CustomResponse (originalResponse) {
  this.restifyResponse = originalResponse
  this.type = 'customResponse'
}

CustomResponse.prototype.send = function (code, payload) {
  if (!payload) { payload = code }

  console.log(payload)  
  this.restifyResponse.send(code, payload)
}

module.exports = CustomResponse
```

I'm trying to use this module in a **middleware** but it doesn't work :

```
  var CustomResponse = require('./customResponse') // the file above

  server.use(function (req, response, next) {
    response = new customResponse(response)
    next()
  })
```

This works only when I use it in a **route** :

```
 var CustomResponse = require('./customResponse') // the file above

 server.get({
   path: '/foo/bar'
 }, function(request, response, next){
     response = new CustomResponse(response)
     response.send('baz') // this will print on the console the response and send it to the browser
 })
```

Thanks for any hint !

Answer (score 0):

This is your middleware?

```
 var CustomResponse = require('./customResponse') // the file above

  server.use(function (req, response, next) {
    response = new Response(response)
    next()
  })
```

For this code:

```
response = new Response(response)
```

I think you should use it like the following code

```
response = new CustomResponse(response)
```

Because the variable you are using is `CustomResponse`, not `Response`.

I hope it's help.

Comment: Thanks titus it was a typo, but still it's not working ... as if I can't modify the response object in the middleware vs request

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but I have tried it and I can do it here. What is the error information?